# How to check which Kubernetes pod is responding during load balancing?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-pod

I have a simple web app deployed on kubernetes.

I have two Pods and Service for them.
Requests should be balanced among two pods. How I can verify this?

Maybe there are some tools or commands?
When I hit (make request) my application, I want to see something like this in console:

```
request on pod1
request on pod2
request on pod2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your application is logging something during a request you can tail the logs from both of the container, you can use [stern](https://github.com/wercker/stern)

```
kubectl logs pods-1 -f
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be add the podname or podip or hostname or some other identifier to an HTTP header before sending back a response from the pod to the client . Then in the client side you can inspect the header to check which pod responded for that particular request.

For example you could define env in your pod as below

```
env:
  - name: MY_POD_NAME
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.name
  - name: MY_POD_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.podIP
```

Then you could read the environment variables `MY_POD_NAME` and `MY_POD_IP`, add them into an http header, print them in logs.

Comment: It's good solution, but it need to add changes to your code. Because of this I choose another answer as correct. (@Rémi F)
Nevertheless your variant could be used in some cases.